# How to set different url in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

Here is a css code block.

```
<style type="text/css">
    header.intro-header{
        position: relative;
        background-image: url('{{ site.baseurl }}/{% if page.header-img %}{{ page.header-img }}{% else %}{{ site.header-img }}{% endif %}')
    }
</style>
```

I want to do such thing : if site.baseurl contains `http` I want to remove `site.baseurl` prefix , otherwise I wan to add `site.baseurl` prefix.

Can anyone help me ? I am new to `css`

## EDIT

Thanks for friends who has commented. I am using `jeklly` theme. In every markdown, there is such line: `header-img: "xx"`. As you see, the actural url of header-img is above css code.

Comment: Are you using some server side code? (`{% if`).

Comment: How about if you use `img` tag and do that part in template for `img`'s `src` attribute?

Comment: I think you are using something like jekyll and this question seems to be specific to that.

Comment: @Tomato I just updated my question.

Comment: I think you want to remove the {{ site.baseurl }}/ part when the header-img starts with http. Am I right?

Comment: @Tomato You are right.

Comment: Then probably you want to resolve every relative URL to that base URL, so the most logical thing would be to add `<base href="{{ site.baseurl }}">` to your markup and then the background-image can be just `background-image: url('{% if page.header-img %}{{ page.header-img }}{% else %}{{ site.header-img }}{% endif %}')`.

Comment: Where should I add `<base href="{{ site.baseurl }}">` ?

Comment: Anywhere to the HTML document. For example, directly above the `<style type="text/css">`

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not a programming language so a traditional conditional block is not possible in that sense. You can achieve you goal still by using Javascript or your programming language of choice to check if the base URL contains a certain string and print your URL value based on the result.